# Unable to get the target element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple gallery using javascript but everytime i click on a thumbnail, the `screen` or the biggest picture( the main picture i mean) isn't changing.

```
    <div id='headImage'>
    <img src='bron.jpg' id='screen' height='300' width='400'/>

</div>


<div id='imagelist' onclick='changeImage(event)'>
    <img src='bron.jpg' height='150' width='150'/>
    <img src='curry2.jpg'  height='150' width='150'/>
    <img src='irving.jpg' height='150' width='150'/>
    <img src='phelps.jpg'  height='150' width='150'/>
    <img src='stonie.jpg' height='150' width='150'/>



</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function changeImage(event)
{
    event = event || window.event;


    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

        //if(targetElement ='IMG'){
            document.getElementById("screen").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
        //}
}
</script>
```

Comment: your function is called changeImage, but you say onclick="cange()". change  the onclick to: `onclick="changeImage();"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

```
<div id='imagelist' onclick()='change(event)'>
```

But correct syntax is:

```
<div id='imagelist' onclick='change(event)'>
```

And your function changeImage(event) is only called if you write the correct name:

```
<div id='imagelist' onclick='changeImage(event)'>
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice eyes. Answer to be marked after 8 minutes :)